# Card Layout - Get Input from previous Card

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, cardlayout

I need a running order of pages 1-5 pages. I am using the card layout to navigate between each page after entering data on each page. The navigation to the next page works via an Action Listener on each text field.

My question is how do I pass the input from each card/page to the next? I can System.out.println each TextFeilds data. But I can't grab this information in the next card/action listener. The reason I need this to happen is I'd like to compare the strings of each page and also display a label of page 1's input on page/card2.

I apologize in advance for the massive block of code... Most of you will recognise most of this code anyway as it's copied from the CardLayout sample java code. I have just added two cards just now until I get the basics of passing variables back and fourth.

All help is appreciated even a small push the the right direction.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CardLayoutDemo implements ItemListener  {
    JPanel cards; //a panel that uses CardLayout
    final static String TEXTPANEL =  "Card1 with text";
    final static String TEXTPANEL2 = "Card with JTextField";

public void addComponentToPane(Container pane) {
        //Put the JComboBox in a JPanel to get a nicer look.
        JPanel comboBoxPane = new JPanel(); //use FlowLayout
        String comboBoxItems[] = { TEXTPANEL, TEXTPANEL2};
        JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(comboBoxItems);
        cb.setEditable(false);
        cb.addItemListener(this);
        comboBoxPane.add(cb);

    //Create the "cards".

    JPanel card1 = new JPanel(); 
        JTextField jtf=new JTextField("", 40);
        jtf.setSize(40, 10);
        card1.add(jtf);

        JLabel lab1 = new JLabel("Page1 Text", JLabel.LEFT);
            card1.add(lab1 = new JLabel("Page1"));

    JPanel card2 = new JPanel();
        JTextField jtf2=new JTextField("", 40);
        jtf2.setSize(40, 10);
    card2.add(jtf2);
        JLabel lab2 = new JLabel("Page2 Text", JLabel.LEFT);
        card2.add(lab2 = new JLabel("Page2 "));

     //Create the panel that contains the "cards".
    cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
    cards.add(card1, TEXTPANEL);
    cards.add(card2, TEXTPANEL2);
    pane.add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);

jtf.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{

  String getText1 = jtf.getText();
                System.out.println("PAGE1 ");
                System.out.println(getText1);

    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());
    cl.show(cards, TEXTPANEL2);  
         jtf2.requestFocus();
         jtf2.requestFocusInWindow();


     } 


    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Action Listener is working");
    });


  //PAGE2

     jtf2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

    String getText2 = jtf2.getText();
                System.out.println("PAGE2 ");
                System.out.println(getText2);

    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());
    cl.show(cards, TEXTPANEL);  
         jtf.requestFocus();
         jtf.requestFocusInWindow();
         jtf.setText("");

    }

    });

    }//ADD COMPONENT TO PANE

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {
    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());
    cl.show(cards, (String)evt.getItem());

  //      String getLoginUser1 = jtf.getText();
    //System.out.println(getLoginUser1); 


    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event dispatch thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("CardLayoutDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 300));
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

    //Create and set up the content pane.
    CardLayoutDemo demo = new CardLayoutDemo();
    demo.addComponentToPane(frame.getContentPane());

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Use an appropriate Look and Feel */
    try {
        //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


    /* Turn off metal's use of bold fonts */
    UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);

    //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();

        }
    });
    }
    }
```

Comment: A cursory glance at your question suggests that you want to use an model-view-controller or MVC type pattern so that the model (the underlying program logic and data) is extracted out of the view (the GUI).

Comment: ...........hello??

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply :) I apologize for taking a while to get back. I will have a look at this today I have been busy with other things and I've not had a chance to implement the suggestions mentioned...

Answer (score 1):

Here is another view on the problem. You could create some kind of cards manager and hold all required info inside of it. Here is an example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CardLayoutDemo implements ItemListener  {

    private static class QuizManager {
        final  java.util.List<String> quizData = new ArrayList<>();
        final  java.util.List<JPanel> cards = new ArrayList<>();
        final  JPanel rootView;

        public QuizManager(JPanel root){
            rootView = root;
        }

        private JPanel createQuizPanel(String pageText, final int index) {
            JPanel card = new JPanel();
            JTextField jtf=new JTextField("", 40);
            jtf.setSize(40, 10);
            JLabel prev = new JLabel("", JLabel.LEFT);
            card.add(prev);
            card.add(jtf);
            card.add(new JLabel(pageText, JLabel.LEFT));


            jtf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    QuizManager.this.onCardSubmited(card, index, jtf.getText());
                }
            });

            card.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
                    super.componentShown(e);
                    jtf.requestFocus();
                    jtf.requestFocusInWindow();
                    String text = QuizManager.this.getPrevStringFor(index);
                    if (text != null) {
                        prev.setText(text);
                    }
                }
            });

            return card;
        }

        private String getPrevStringFor(int index) {
            if (index == 0) return null;

            return quizData.get(index-1);
        }
        private String buildPanelName(int index) {
            return String.format("card-%d", index);
        }
        public QuizManager addCard(String title) {
            int index = cards.size();
            quizData.add(null);//not set yet, just allocating
            JPanel card = createQuizPanel(title, index);
            cards.add(card);//this array looks like redundant
            rootView.add(card, buildPanelName(index));
            return this;
        }

        private void showCard(int index) {
            CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (rootView.getLayout());
            cl.show(rootView, buildPanelName(index));
        }

        public void show() {
            showCard(0);
        }

        public void onCardSubmited(JPanel card, int cardIndex, String text) {
            System.out.println("page " + cardIndex);
            System.out.println("text : " + text);
            quizData.set(cardIndex, text);
            if (cardIndex < cards.size() - 1) {
                showCard(cardIndex + 1);
            } else {
                System.out.println("WE FINISHED");
                //add finalazing code here
            }
        }
    }

    JPanel cardsRoot;
    public void addComponentToPane(Container pane) {
        cardsRoot = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        QuizManager manager = new QuizManager(cardsRoot)
                .addCard("First page")
                .addCard("Second page")
                .addCard("Third card")
                .addCard("Forth card");

        pane.add(cardsRoot, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        manager.show();
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cardsRoot.getLayout());
        cl.show(cardsRoot, (String)evt.getItem());
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event dispatch thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("CardLayoutDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 300));
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        CardLayoutDemo demo = new CardLayoutDemo();
        demo.addComponentToPane(frame.getContentPane());

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Use an appropriate Look and Feel */
        try {
            //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }


    /* Turn off metal's use of bold fonts */
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);

        //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Take a look how easy would be to create many of cards.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i am looking to do, Is there a way to add each page's input to an array?

Comment: It's already in a list inside of `QuizManager` - `quizData`. Just add a getter method to extract it if you need it to access outside

Comment: Дякую ! I really appreciate the help :)!

Comment: Hello, Not sure if i need to ask a new question. I am looking for an image to be displayed based on the input of the previous page. 

This would only occur on page 3. i.e I'd like Page 4(card5) to display Page3's(Card4) input. I tried adding the code below but it only adds it on page 3 not page 4.
       
              
                       ImageIcon background = new ImageIcon("test.jpg");
             JLabel label = new JLabel();
             
            label.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 500);
            label.setIcon(background);
            card.add(label);

Answer (score 0):

You've got the variable declaration of key components buried within the `addComponentToPane(...)` method, limiting their scope to this method only, preventing you from getting the information you need. While the canonical solution for this sort of problem is to use an model-view-controller or MVC type pattern so that the model (the underlying program logic and data) is extracted out of the view (the GUI), you can do a quick and dirty solution just by giving your variables private class scope.

For instance, if the JTextField was called textField and was held in a JPanel that acts as a "card", say called cardPanel, you could create a class that looked something like so:

```
public class CardPanel extends JPanel {
    // constants to give the GUI a bigger size
    private static final int PREF_W = 300;
    private static final int PREF_H = 100;

    // our key JTextField declared at class level
    private JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);

    // a JLabel to display the previous cardpanel's text
    private JLabel label = new JLabel(" ");

    // create the JPanel
    public CardPanel(String name) {
        setName(name);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Panel " + name));
        JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        labelPanel.add(new JLabel("Prior Card's Word: "));
        labelPanel.add(label);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(textField, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    // have to jump through this hoop if we want to JTextField to
    // have focus when a card is swapped
    public void setFocusOnTextField() {
        textField.requestFocusInWindow();
        textField.selectAll();
    }

    // to make our GUI larger
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    // allow outside classes to add a listener to the JTextField
    public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        textField.addActionListener(listener);
    }

    // allow outside classes to get text from the text field 
    public String getTextFieldText() {
        return textField.getText();
    }

    // allow outside classes to put text into the JLabel 
    public void setLabelText(String text) {
        label.setText(text);
    }
}
```

And then we could use it like so:

```
public class MyCardLayoutDemo extends JPanel {
    private static final String[] NAMES = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four"};
    private Map<String, CardPanel> namePanelMap = new HashMap<>();
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    private int nameIndex = 0;

    public MyCardLayoutDemo() {
        setLayout(cardLayout);
        MyListener listener = new MyListener();

        for (String name : NAMES) {
            CardPanel cardPanel = new CardPanel(name);
            cardPanel.addActionListener(listener);
            add(cardPanel, name);
            namePanelMap.put(name, cardPanel);
        }
    }

    private class MyListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // get the current CardPanel
            String name = NAMES[nameIndex];
            CardPanel currentCard = namePanelMap.get(name);

            // advance the name index to get the next CardPanel
            nameIndex++;
            nameIndex %= NAMES.length;
            name = NAMES[nameIndex];
            CardPanel nextCard = namePanelMap.get(name);

            // get text from current CardPanel
            String text = currentCard.getTextFieldText();
            nextCard.setLabelText(text);  // and put it into next one

            // swap cards
            cardLayout.show(MyCardLayoutDemo.this, name);
            nextCard.setFocusOnTextField();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MyCardLayoutDemo mainPanel = new MyCardLayoutDemo();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My CardLayout Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```